# jquery ui css and image files are in a different folder, how to configure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery ui, I downloaded the entire toolset.

I put the css and images into a folder like:

```
/images/jquery/base/
/images/jquery/ui-lightness/
```

How can I configure this so it works?

(if that's possible)

Answer (score 2):

That is normal virtual pathing, meaning you'll have to reconfigure your .js and css files inside the plugins to look for the new path. IMO just use the default way, create an extra 'plugins' or 'extras' folder or something and avoid the trouble.

Comment: what is the default anyhow? what folder should I drop the theme in?

Comment: check out the demos folder in your download, did you use the themeroller (http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to get your theme?